# the logic in my python program doesnt seem to work

Tags: python, python-3.x

ok so i am new to python and i have problem with some logic in python.I want to make a piece of code that is going to read the information from my dictionary and then display the key and the value when a keyword in registered with the user input.
this is my code so far....and for some reason only the keyword 'mama' seems kinda work..it displays the value of the key 'mama' and the value of the key 'tata'
the code finally:

```
imena_i_rodjendani={'mama':'1-2-1981','lovro':'3-12-2004','tata':'1-5-1982'}
ime=str(input("ime: "))

if ime==str('mama'):
    print(imena_i_rodjendani.get('mama'))
    if ime==str('lovro'):
        print(imena_i_rodjendani.get('lovro'))
    else:
        print(imena_i_rodjendani.get('tata'))
```

All the other inputs except the input 'mama' seem to just give no crap of the logic i've written and they simply end the program without any error.
P.S. tell me if i am using the site wrong or if i am asking the questions in a wrong way.Thank you to anyone reading this post in advance!

Comment: As for how to use the site: you should up vote answers that are helpful, and be sure to mark the correct answer (green check). Not only does that award rep to the answerer, but more importantly it helps future readers of the question know what worked to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `elif` to put the other two tests on the same level as the test for `'mama'`; otherwise `ime` needs to be `'mama'` first in order to be tested for `'lovro'`, which can never happen.

```
imena_i_rodjendani={'mama':'1-2-1981','lovro':'3-12-2004','tata':'1-5-1982'}
ime=str(input("ime: "))

if ime==str('mama'):
    print(imena_i_rodjendani.get('mama'))
elif ime==str('lovro'):
    print(imena_i_rodjendani.get('lovro'))
else:
    print(imena_i_rodjendani.get('tata'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python uses whitespace to delimit structure. Your indentation is incorrect. Also, you likely want to use the keyword `elif`. Try this:

```
imena_i_rodjendani={'mama':'1-2-1981','lovro':'3-12-2004','tata':'1-5-1982'}
ime=str(input("ime: "))

if ime==str('mama'):
    print(imena_i_rodjendani.get('mama'))
elif ime==str('lovro'):
    print(imena_i_rodjendani.get('lovro'))
else:
    print(imena_i_rodjendani.get('tata'))
```

Edit:
You may consider a different approach to your problem that is more robust. First thing to note, `input()` already returns a string, so there's no need to cast it. Second, you may want to utilize the features of your dictionary, rather than hard-coding a bunch of logic for each option.
For example:

```
imena_i_rodjendani={'mama':'1-2-1981','lovro':'3-12-2004','tata':'1-5-1982'}
ime=input("ime: ")

if ime in imena_i_rodjendani:
    print(imena_i_rodjendani[ime])
else:
    print('ime not found!')
```

This will handle the condition that the user didn't enter a known value, and it will allow you to add new values to your dictionary without having to explicitly code additional conditions for each one.